# Vue3 Modify props from slot

Tags: vuejs3, vue-slot

I´ve been trying for days to achieve the following since I'm building a generic component.

Is there a y way I can pass a generic form as a slot and the slot be responsible to change the props?

I'm not sure if this is even possible, I don't quite understand how slots work if they are named.

Here´s an example of what I'm trying to do.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-szkqcr?file=src/App.vue

The idea is to have a single component that has edit and read-only versions, but I would like to be able to edit from the edit slot.

Comment: Props are read only and you could change them by passing them dynamically from the upper parent.

Comment: I still don't understand what needs to be modified, sorry